# php- replace a string within a string

Tags: php, string, wordpress, search, replace

Hi I have the following search form:

```
<form method='get'><input type='text' name='searchvalue' value='<? if (isset($_GET['searchvalue'])) echo $_GET['searchvalue'];?>' />&nbsp;<input type='submit' value='Search' /><input type='hidden' name='pagenum' value='1' /></form>
```

It is part of a wordpress plugin that accesses an API and returns search results, when I send the search data to the api, `file_get_contents("$api_url/book/index.php/name/$searchvalue?key=$api_key");` the query, if it has spaces, needs to be formated like this: `This%20Is%20An%20Example` instead it is being formated like this: `This+Is+An+Example`

I was going to replace the pluses using `str_replace()` as so: `str_replace("+", "%20", $searchvalue);`, but it doesn't seem to be working!

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Use rawurlencode() function.

```
$searchvalue = rawurlencode($searchvalue);
```

This will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make it as the following:

> file_get_contents("$api_url/book/index.php/name/".rawurlencode($searchvalue)."?key=$api_key");

check it the documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php

some general url functions: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.url.php

Answer (score -1):

`$searchvalue = str_replace('+', '%20', $searchvalue);` will do the trick.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Answer (score -1):

1. Accordance to the documentation, link to PHP manual mentioned by Casimir et Hippolyte, first parameter is search string, in Your case '+', second parameter is string in which search will be replaced, in Your case '%20'. So You command seems to be properly.
2. But ensure that You assign return from function value to variable, because str_replace don't change given string value like method on the object. It's function and it "only" returns changed string as value.

Apart from the facts that:

- manually modifying WP plugins is usually not a good idea
- WP with it's plugins is very complex system and sometimes it's hard to decipher all performing with your code actions. As far as possible always in similar case test minimum, problematic part code separatly by WordPress.